# Python unexpectantly crashing when you execute a code?

Tags: python, debugging

Has anyone had Python quit on them whenever they execute a code (that you know is correct because you have run it before) and you get this error:

```
ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
AssertionError

Unfortunately, your original traceback can not be constructed.

ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
AssertionError

Unfortunately, your original traceback can not be constructed.

ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
AssertionError

Unfortunately, your original traceback can not be constructed.

Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    %config Application.verbose_crash=True

Ambers-MBP:spectra AmberRoberts$ ipython
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 19 2015, 18:31:17) 

Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.  
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: python 2.7.10 Anaconda 2.4.0

Comment: That's version information.  I mean are you running Windows, Linux, Mac, etc.?

Comment: What code are you executing? Please update your post along with code. See what debugger is saying. **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**